# Pyside2, DLL load failed in samplebinding example

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2, shiboken2

Trying to get the [samplebinding example](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/05/31/write-python-bindings) working, but no matter the compiler, python or pyside version used, I still get

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing Universe: The specified module could not be found.

Last configuration used:

- VS2019
- cmake 3.16.2
- python 3.81 amd64 from python.org
- pyside2, shiboken2 5.14.1 from pip
- shiboken-generator whl 5.14.1 from [here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/QtForPython/)

Library is compiling fine:

[image: Shell snapshot]

Comment: @eyllanesc added to PATH, or to PYTHONPATH, still got the error. I think is some sort of binary conflict, maybe the compiled shiboken-generator WHL and the python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.8 changed the dll path resolution.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#bpo-36085-whatsnew)

Adding the shiboken2.abi3.dll to the folder resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the import to be Python3 compatible:

```
from build.Universe import Icecream, Truck
```

The import of `__future__.print_function` suggests the file is still written for Python2.